# Make grayscale on layer NOT <img/> in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, internet-explorer-11

How to make equivalent of

```
.anyClass
{
   filter:grayscale(100%); 
}
```

in IE11 for elements **other than `<img/>`?**

The code doesn't have to work in IE10 and earlier and other browsers.

I googled some solutions like:

```
.anyClass
{
   filter:gray; /* IE9 */
   filter:grayscale(100%); 
   -ms-filter:grayscale(100%);
   -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); 
}
```

but it doesn't work on IE10 and IE11.

I also found solutions for `<img/>` but I want to use it on standard HTML elements like `<div/>`, `<section/>` (with elements internal it).

No found solution works.

BTW. The code may not work in other browsers. I know how to filter IE11. JS (without jQuery), CSS, SVG and HTML allowed.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532889(v=vs.85).aspx But apparently it's a boolean (only 0% and 100%)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. F12: `var obj=document.querySelector('.window');
`obj -> <section class="window ...`
`obj.filters -> undefined`
These filters worked for IE5-IE9. Also filter:gray worked.